# How to integrate module?

Tags: c, linux, module, window, integrated

I want to integrate the function I created I am trying to create a website that judges cheating.
Currently, it has implemented several functions, such as searching for cheating items or recognizing identity.
The only thing left now is to build a website, receive a video from the website in real time, apply the function I created to the video, and notify the user's website in case of cheating through the result.
I have to apply various functions to the video or photo received from the web page.
Also, these functions are composed of various development languages(c, python) and some were developed under Windows and others under Linux.
I would like to recommend how to integrate each function or search terms related to it and some tips!!
It's my first time integrating, so I don't know anything.
And I'm not good at English, so please explain it easily...

Comment: Im not sure on your overall requirement, what I understand is you want to create a website and you have some code written in c and python. Since you know little python, you can get started with creating website using python's Django framework. This link should help you get started.  

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/skeleton_website

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].